# Why aren't my resources apprearing in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image: the resource pack folder is gone]

In Minecraft my resources don't appear and it's very annoying. I need help, this has been happening ever since the 1.17 migration where it transferred all the data to a different location in my files (supposedly) but it also has aspects of 1.18 like the seeds for the deep dark but without the deep dark itself.

My game seems broken and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! What do you mean by resources? In your inventory?

Comment: my resource packs and its internal storage is gone, i didnt even delete the folder. the external files are present externally but not internally. i think it had something to do with the file migration for 1.17

Comment: Did you zip the file before migrating it?

Comment: i dont need to, its the default resource folder that comes with the app in the game files!